# Change navbar text color on scroll

Tags: javascript, navbar

I'm quite new to coding in general and can't really understand why this doesn't work.
The original color of `.nav__links` and `.logo` is `#fff` so I wrote the following codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 865 ) {
      $(".nav__links a").css("color", "#D76766");
    }
    else if ($(document).scrollTop() < 1629 ) {
      $(".nav__links a").css("color", "#fff");
    }
  });
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 865 ) {
        $(".logo").css("color", "#D76766");
      }
      else if ($(document).scrollTop() < 1629 ) {
        $(".logo").css("color", "#fff");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and/or

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
  if (window.scrollY >= 0 && window.scrollY  < 864) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav__links").css("color", "#fff");
    document.getElementsByClassName("logo").css("color", "#fff");
  } 
  else if (window.scrollY  > 865 && window.scrollY  < 1629) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav__links").css("color", "#D76766");
    document.getElementsByClassName("logo").css("color", "#D76766");
  } 
  else if (window.scrollY  > 1630 && window.scrollY  < 4000) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav__links").css("color", "#fff");
    document.getElementsByClassName("logo").css("color", "#fff"); 
  }
}
```

With this thought process:

1. if the original color is white, then it will start as white so from 0 to 864 the color will be white;
2. from 865 to 1629 it changes to #D76766
3. from 1630 to the end of the page it goes back to white.

In the first code, the `nav` starts as white, changes to `#D76766` but doesn't change back to white. As for the second code, it doesn't work at all. The navbar is white throughout the entire page.

I would appreciate any help at all :)

Comment: Note to answerers: while fixing formatting/indentation, I noticed that the jQuery code sample was missing a closing `})`, and so added that. I think that's not the core problem (just bad copy/paste), but my apologies if that invalidates some of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is an error in the if sequence, when you put this

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 865 ) {
    $(".nav__links a").css("color", "#D76766");
} 
else if ($(document).scrollTop() < 1629 ) {
    $(".nav__links a").css("color", "#fff");
}
```

The nav_link color would turn to white only when the scrollTop() is <= 865,
but not when it is >= 1630, as 1630 is always higher than 865 and the first condition would be true.
Te correct code should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    let pos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (pos >= 865 && pos <= 1629) {
      $(".nav__links a").css("color", "#D76766");
      $(".logo").css("color", "#D76766");
    } 
    else {
      $(".nav__links a").css("color", "#fff");
      $(".logo").css("color", "#fff");
    }
  });
});
```

The color would turn to #D76766 only when the position of the scrollbar is between 865 and 1629, if this isn´t true, the color would return to white

Comment: Hey! Thank you for answering!
I tried to replace my code with yours but the navbar stays white throughout the entire page... any idea why?

Comment: I did not put the complete code, i have just modified it, try now!

Comment: Well that was much easier than I thought! Sorry for asking for such a simple task. And thank you, again!!